# custom Image for Bottom Navigation bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, bottomnavigationview

What I want to do is a custom colored image like this,
What I tried is making a layer list like this

```
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:bottom="20dp"
    >
</item>
<item
    android:top="20dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_selected_indicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
</item>
```

But it will be shown white not orange and white

then I created a an image containing the two items and the image Shown as white !!!!

not forget to mention I added the selector like this.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected_home"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" 
                                 android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected_home"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home"/>
  </selector>
```

[image: Image of Bottom nav bar]